# Is there a way to use a string to pick a variable?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

Let's say we have the following code to switch between sprites in an animation. There are eight directions (north, north-east, east, etcetera). We switch between them and now we pick a sprite based on the animation cycle. Here is the code:

```
switch (direction){
    case 0: // south
        switch(sprite){
            case 0: return moveSouth0;
            case 1: return moveSouth1;
            case 2: return moveSouth2;
            case 3: return moveSouth3;
        }
    case 1: // south-east
        switch(sprite){
            case 0: return moveSouthEast0;
            case 1: return moveSouthEast1;
            case 2: return moveSouthEast2;
            case 3: return moveSouthEast3;
        }
    case 2: // east
        switch(sprite){
            case 0: return moveEast0;
            case 1: return moveEast1;
            case 2: return moveEast2;
            case 3: return moveEast3;
        }
    case 3: // northeast
    // etcetera
}
```

This works. The variables "*moveSouth0*, *moveSouth1*", etcetera, are `BufferedImage` variables.

However, it is very long and the same code is being used. My ideal scenario is to do the following:

```
String s;
switch (direction){
    case 0: // south
        s = "South";
        break;
    case 1: // south-east
        s = "SouthEast";
        break;
    // etcetera
}
return "move" + s + sprite; // <- now returns string, should return BufferedImage
```

As you can see, here I don't have to make 8 more switch clauses in each direction case.
Obviously this doesn't work because I have to return a `BufferedImage` and I am now returning a `String`.

**Q: So what I am looking for is a way to change a `String` into the name of a variable**.

Is such a thing even possible (in Java)?

Comment: Are your BufferedImage's member variables of a class or are they locals?

Comment: @MrPixelDream they are member variables

Comment: What about setting up all your directions using an enumerable type and calling the .name() or .toString() method on it in your return?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

Comment: @Chronicle I wrote an answer for you. With member variables, its possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **IS** possible but I wouldn't recommend doing it, since basically it's not a good style.

Here's how you could do it:

```
Field field = YourClass.class.getField("nameOfTheVarGoesHere");  
BufferedImage sprite = (BufferedImage) field.get(this);
```

However, even though it is possible, you should stay with your current switch in my opinion.

Comment: I am guessing that "it not being good style" is because of slower performance?

Comment: To be honest, i am not sure about the performance but Reflection is basically a tool to inspect objects and stuff and not a tool to do something which isnt provided by the language by default.

Answer (score 4):

I'll rephrase that. While it can be done via reflection, it would be ugly, unsafe (since, as you see in the other answer, you have to supply the variable name as a String, and if you put a name of an un-existing variable, the compiler won't catch your error, and you'll get an exception at runtime) and less efficient.

Therefore what you should do is store all these variables in a single array and use the index of the array to determine which of them is returned.

A two dimensional array would be even better.

```
BufferedImage[][] move = ...;
...
return move[directionIndex][spriteIndex];
```

Comment: What about reflections? Its not good style to do it that way but its possible.